tube lemma and set containment
Consider topological spaces $X,Y$. Assume $K$ compact in $X\times Y$ and $O$ is open $X\times Y$. Assume $K\subseteq O$. Can we find a $O_1,O_2$ open such that $K\subseteq O_1\times O_2\subseteq O$?
(1).If $K=K_1\times K_2$ then yes.
(2).Why is this a special case of the tube lemma?

In general, the answer is no. Consider the following counterexample in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$K = [0,1]^2 \cup ([0,3] \times [0.5,1])$.
$O = \{p\in \mathbb{R}^2 | d(p,K)<r\}$ for some small $r>0$. Here $d(p,K)$ represents the shortest distance from any point in $K$ to $p$.
In order for $O_1\times O_2$ to contain $K$, we must have $O_1 \supset [0,3]$ and $O_2 \supset [0,1]$. But this implies that $(3,0)\in O_1\times O_2$, but $(3,0)\not\in O$ when $r$ is sufficiently small. Thus $O_1\times O_2 \not\subset O $.
As you said, this lemma is true when $K$ is a product. Can you think of what happens when $K$ is a tube or union/intersection of tubes?
